# What should I enter for the profile link in /contact?

Tags: support, deleted-users

I can't seem to get my correct profile link for the Contact Support: https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact

The error I get is "oops! this isn't a link to a valid profile"

I've tried these and more..

- meta.stackoverflow.com/users/id/username
- meta.stackoverflow.com/users/id/
- stackoverflow.com/users/id/username
- stackoverflow.com/users/id/

I've even tried just a username or just the id

How do I get what they are asking?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7819783

Comment: Thanks but still dosnt work.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Navigating to a profile using the provide links works. Navigating to a non-existent id returns a 404, not that error message. Please [edit] to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you trying to enter that url on the Contact Us page, by any chance?

Comment: @rene - Yes thats it. Trying to contact support.

Comment: Did you include the http:// or https:// in front of those urls? And which option did you select from the the *What can we help you with?* drop down?

Comment: @rene - Yes I did include http:// and the topic is delete account.

Comment: same "oops! this isn't a link to a valid profile" issue, no matter if you use  https://stackexchange.com/users/$validid/$valididname, or https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/$validid/$valididname,  If you omit the https:// in the url, the error message 'smartly" changed into "Profile links must be for Stack Exchange sites".
frustrating!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I edited your question here to include the critical detail that you left out: you were using the "contact us" form *on Meta Stack Exchange!*

You don't have a profile on Meta Stack Exchange.

The reason we put such strict validation on this form is that folks would contact us from one site using a link to their profile on another site, or sometimes just a user ID on another site. The inevitable result was...

- ...best-case, we caught this and did the right thing.
- ...next-best case, we figured out the link or ID was bogus and replied asking for more information.
- ...next-to-worst-case, we deleted the wrong profile for the user who'd asked for deletion.
- ...absolute-worst-case, we deleted *someone else's profile.*

Now, we usually impose other checks to avoid the worst-case scenarios. But still, the risk is troubling. Especially now that we *automate* most account deletions, so no humans are involved beyond the person requesting deletion. **It is *essential* that we collect and confirm the correct profile to be deleted!**

If you want your Stack Overflow profile to be deleted, go to [the Contact Us page on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and request it there. Since you're already logged in, we'll even pre-fill the correct profile link, so you don't need to worry about the format.

Comment: To be fair, the error message doesn't tell the user anything, it just says that the profile link is invalid. I wouldn't blame someone for assuming that the contact form was network-wide, even if that isn't actually the case.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point; it's more descriptive if you enter a URL to a *different user*, but a URL to the wrong *site* doesn't give much of a hint.

Comment: shog9: you did not get what the original question was asking about!!!  the original question was (and still is) crystal clear and valid as hell, if you had tried to merge two accounts yourself and fill the form https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact/submit, you would understand much better.   somehow the issue remains there unsolved!

Comment: @waterstone You seem confused. There isn't anything left to "solve" here. Maybe ask a new Meta question instead (preferably with a milder tone).